# How to only report failures from a type of exception with pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Is there a way I can tell pytest to ignore all failing tests but a type of exception I choose.

For instance, I would like pytest to only tell me about tests that raises `IndexError`, and nothing about the rest.

```
def test_a():
    raise IndexError()

def test_b():
    1/0 # this test would be ignored

def test_c():
    raise KeyError() # this test would also be ignored
```

Note that I have 3000+ tests and I cannot edit each test to add markers. I just want to find those which generate IndexError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that I have 3000+ tests and I cannot edit each test to add markers.

You can add markers dynamically. Example: add the following code in your `conftest.py`:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    xfail_exceptions = (IndexError, KeyError)
    for item in items:
        item.add_marker(pytest.mark.xfail(raises=xfail_exceptions))
```

Now all tests will be automatically marked, raising only on exceptions that are not listed in `xfail_exceptions`.

You can extend this even further and parametrize the exceptions from command line:

```
import importlib
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--ex', action='append', default=[], help='exception classes to xfail')


def class_from(name):
    modname, clsname = name.rsplit('.', 1)
    mod = importlib.import_module(modname)
    return getattr(mod, clsname)


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    xfail_exceptions = tuple((class_from(name) for name in pytest.config.getoption('--ex')))
    if xfail_exceptions:
        for item in items:
            item.add_marker(pytest.mark.xfail(raises=xfail_exceptions))
```

Usage example:

```
$ pytest --ex builtins.KeyError --ex builtins.IndexError -sv
================================== test session starts ====================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.7.3, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.7.1
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow, inifile:
plugins: django-3.4.2
collected 3 items

test_spam.py::test_a xfail
test_spam.py::test_b FAILED
test_spam.py::test_c xfail

======================================== FAILURES =========================================
_________________________________________ test_b __________________________________________

    def test_b():
>       1/0 # this test would be ignored
E       ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

test_spam.py:5: ZeroDivisionError
========================== 1 failed, 2 xfailed in 0.08 seconds ============================
```

Answer (score 0):

Pytest let you add an XFail decorator to decide if you want your test to fail on a specific exception:

```
@pytest.mark.xfail(raises= IndexError)
def test_function():
    test_here
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html)

Edit:

you might want to add the `strict=true` param as well, like this:

```
@pytest.mark.xfail(raises= IndexError, strict=True)
def test_function():
    test_here
```

This will fail the suite if this requirement is not met AKA the test didnt fail on IndexError (the default for XFail tests is not to fail the suite even if they dont throw the error)

Comment: Ok I forgot to tell that I have 3000+ test functions and I cannot edit every tests.

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html - checkout the "Marking whole classes or modules" section, should provide a good solution assuming you have a base test class you inherit from

Answer (score 0):

Just have your code look for the error, but then have it continue and execute. Try adding this:

```
except (KeyError, IndexError):
    pass
```

This will handle the exception, but it will do nothing and your program will continue.

Comment: Ok I forgot to tell that I have 3000+ test functions and I cannot edit every tests.

Comment: I think exceptions are categorized in a heirarchy, so you could have it just ignore the entire library of Exceptions